# Why is Google Analytics reporting pageviews for a page without tracking code installed?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have a site that's incorrectly tagged, so GA tracking is only placed on some of the pages (that's not the problem - I can fix this!).

As you'd expect, [GA reports these pages without the tracking code installed as an error](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6006306?hl=en&utm_id=ad#trackingcode).

But **some of these pages without the tracking code are still reporting pageviews in GA. How could this be happening?** Or, more likely, what's actually going on that I've missed? ;-)

(NB. I've checked and it's not a case of the code being removed at some point but still showing historic data.)

Comment: Is it tracking clicks, perhaps? You would think it would only track pages that have run the GA code, but do you have it setup to track clicks for the pages that actually have the code? I'm as perplexed as you.

Comment: Are these pageviews consistent or more erratic?

Comment: No event tracking to or from the pages if that's what you mean, @philtune?

Comment: @dasickle - consistent, both with itself and another analytics package that *is* installed correctly. Very odd!

Comment: Also NB. as well as GA itself reporting no tracking code installed, GA Debugger is not showing any sends and I can't see anything in the source.

Comment: Can a get an url to look at?